# Oracle DB sql clob column CONCAT performance

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, clob

I am seeking advice on performance of concat operation for CLOB column.

I have job which updates the clob column 'N' times (configurable)  by executing the following query, every time we see performance degrade in the query as clob size increases in other words as column data grows it takes longer time.

```
UPDATE my_table SET file_content = CONCAT(file_content, ?)
 WHERE id = ?
```

Question:- How to improve the performance of above query ?

Update:I am getting suggestions to use `DBMS_LOB.append` Can any body please elaborate this option ?

Thanks

Comment: Everytime the clob size increases, you need to shift more data, which takes longer time. If the time curve looks linear, there is not much you can do...#

Comment: Yes the time graph looks linear.

Comment: Is it 'N' times the same string you add to the clob?

Comment: No. It is different content.

Comment: How do you store the clob, as securefile or basicfile? And how is `CACHE` set for the clob?

Comment: I am storing it as basicfile

Comment: If your version is 11g or later, switch to securefiles, they are a lot faster. The run time of your queries will still depend on the number of cycles, but the differences will be smaller...

Answer (score 1):

We have solved using using following procedure, using 'append'

> create or replace PROCEDURE APPENDCLOB
>   ( CONTENT IN clob,    filetype in varchar2 )
>   AS  fc clob; 
>   BEGIN 
>   SELECT FILE_CONTENT INTO fc FROM my_table where file_type = filetype FOR
>   UPDATE; 
>   dbms_lob.append(fc,CONTENT); 
>   END APPENDCLOB;

Hope that this helps to someone.

Thanks